# Compiling C-OCaml interfacing example from the manual

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to compile C interoperability example from section 19.8 of http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/intfc.html under cygwin (installed through cygwin's official installer), and I get linker error: undefined reference to `flexdll_dlopen'. Anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

OCaml on Cygwin uses flexdll, so

```
cc -c main.c
flexlink -chain cygwin -exe -o prog.exe main.o mod.a -lcurses
```

instead of `cc -o prog main.c mod.a -lcurses`